# SQL Server SQL Select: How do I select rows where sum of a column is within a specified multiple?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a process that needs to select rows from a Table (queued items) each row has a quantity column and I need to select rows where the quantities add to a specific multiple. The mulitple is the order of between around 4, 8, 10 (but could in theory be any multiple. (odd or even)

Any suggestions on how to select rows where the sum of a field is of a specified multiple?

Comment: Are you trying to do Bin Packing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for the link. I suspect its a similar type of problem. The queue is a print queue where we are printing a specific quantitiy of items on a sheet. I have come up with a basic iterative algorithm to check/add quantities in multiples but wondering of there is a more sophosticated SQL solution....(The difference from the Bin example is that we can have any number of sheets, it just needs to be a multiple of x to fill the sheets, to reduce waste etc, ie the 'Bin' can grow in multiples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to use some kind of MOD function which I believe in SQL server is the % sign. So the criteria would be something like this

```
WHERE MyField % 4 = 0 OR MyField % 8 = 0
```

It might not be that fast so another way might be to make a temp table containing say 100 values of the X times table (where X is the multiple you are looking for) and join on that

Comment: Thanks, I am using this within C#, I think the solution is more application that database related, am just trying to find other / more proficient ways to implement things. Will ask this as a C# question.. Thanks forthe top tho!